# Why does {mosmap} not show markers?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, plugin

I am using Joomla plugin "Google Maps" (i.e. plugin_googlemap3). I created a map with markers on Google maps pro and downloaded the kml file. I utilize the {mosmap} call with the kml parameter in the website article.

{mosmap kml='https:///myfile.kml'|centerlat='38.8403'|centerlon='-97.6114'|zoom='4'}

The map is rendered, but no markers are displayed. I have used Google Earth to check the kml file and the markers appear in it. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is something that should be aimed at the developer of the plugin and it's regarding a 3rd party extension

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? You might be able to add 'debug' to your mosmap code above to see what's going wrong. More info at http://tech.reumer.net/Google-Maps/Documentation-of-plugin-Googlemap/parameters-of-plugin-google-maps.html  Another point, I'd strongly recommend installing firebug and using that to see if you get any errors.

Comment: If you view source, can you see the path to the KML file? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Some ideas**:

- Make sure you have followed the instructions correctly and that have
  published and configured anything that is required.
- Also, check if the whole plugin is working correctly or if you may
  get JS conflicts.
- Also, check with a debugger tool if any other errors exist (e.g.
  broken links to markers images files)